# Disconnect all MySQL connections in R

Tags: r, database

I would like to disconnect from all my SQL database connections in R.

Tried to use `closeAllConnections()`, but it doesn't disconnect all connections.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can get all the opened connections with `dbListConnections(MySQL())`. Then you can close all of them. Try something like `lapply(dbListConnections(MySQL()),dbDisconnect)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using database connection pooling with the package `pool` so that you can simply close your pool (`poolClose`) to get rid of all connections. Pooling will also help you organize your connections and prevent leaking or SQL injections.

References:
https://github.com/rstudio/pool
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-advanced.html

**Example:**

```
# install the packages if needed
# install.packages("RMySQL")
# install.packages("pool")

library(pool)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "dbname",
  host = "host",
  username = "username",
  password = "password"
)

poolClose(pool)
```

Comment: installed pool, but cant find the function poolClose

Comment: Updated my answer with a minimal example. The references would provide a better understanding if you could take a look at them.